# Apple Watch: how to align two labels at baseline with different font sizes?

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, watchkit, text-alignment, wkinterfacelabel

On an apple watch, how do I align two labels at baseline with different font sizes?

look at the red and blue labels, they are not aligned at baseline.

[image: align at baseline]
[image: align at baseline]

This is the structure of the first image in the interface builder:

```
horizontal group
    label with big font and Baseline=Align Baseline; Alignment vertical=Center
    label with small font and Baseline=Align Baseline; Alignment vertical=Center
```

This is the structure of the second image in the interface builder:

```
horizontal group
    label with big font and Baseline=Align Baseline; Alignment vertical=Bottom
    label with small font and Baseline=Align Baseline; Alignment vertical=Bottom
```

in the first image, the label with the small font is way too high, in the second image, the label with the small font is a little too low.

How can I make them align exactly at the base line?

Comment: Why not use a single label and `NSAttributedString`?

Comment: it works :-) didn't think of that.

Answer (score -1):

If you're using interface builder, just ctrl + drag from one label to the other and select 'Baseline' to set an align baseline constraint.

Comment: This does not work in watchOS. The way layout is done is different on watchOS than on iOS, and there is no Autolayout, as this answer seems to assume.